# Test passes while exception is thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I've the following test in Nunit with Moq:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MessageServiceTests
{
    private Mock<IFtpClient> _ftpService;
    private IMessageService _messageService;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _ftpService = new Mock<IFtpClient>();

        _messageService = new MessageService(_ftpService.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void SendAsync_WithSettings_ConnectsWithCredentials()
    {
        //act
        _messageService.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Settings>());
    }
    
}
```

and the following method that is tested:

```
 public async Task SendAsync(Stream stream, string fileName, Settings settings)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();            
    }
```

Is expect the test to fail, but when I run it in Visual Studio it passes. I can't get my head around it, tests should fail when an unexpected exception is thrown, right? So why does it pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SendAsync` ran successfully, and returned a `Task` which contained an exception (its `IsFaulted` property returns `true`, and its `Exception` property contains the `NotImplementedException`).

However, you're not checking the `Task` which is returned from `SendAsync`, so you never realise that it contains an exception.

The easiest way to check the `Task` for exceptions is using `await`, and make your test method `async Task`. This also handles the case where the `Task` doesn't complete straight away.

```
[Test]
public async Task SendAsync_WithSettings_ConnectsWithCredentials()
{
    //act
    await _messageService.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<Settings>());
}
```